# How to fire JavaScript event when user drags text into textfield?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a form that formats text which is input by several textfields, and I would like to make it possible for the user to type text, paste text, and drop text into the textfield. The JavaScript event is `format()`. 
I have used the `onkeyup="format()` when a user types text and pastes text, but I can't figure out what event will allow a user to select text, drag and drop it over the textfield, and fire the event to automatically update the formatted text. I have tried `ondrop`, `onmouseup`, and `onchange` all to no avail. 
I have a feeling that the `onmouseup` property is working, but the problem is that the event fires right after the mouse is released, before the text textfield has the new user text, so it looks as if it didn't fire, when indeed it did, but there was nothing in the textfield. Could this be? If so, could I use `setTimeout` to delay the event by 500 milliseconds (or something) until the text is there?

Here is the javscript:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function format() {
     var author = document.form.author.value;
     var credentials = document.form.credentials.value;
     var date = document.form.date.value;
     var publication = document.form.publication.value;
     var title = document.form.title.value;
     var evidence = document.form.evidence.value;
     var tagline = document.form.tagline.value;
     document.getElementById('txtarea').innerHTML = ("<b>" + tagline + "</b>" + "</br >" + "<br />" + "<i>" + "<u>" + author + " " + date + "." + "</u> " + author + " (" + credentials + ") " + date + " " + publication + " " + title + " " + (window.top.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow.location.href) + "</i>" + "<br />" + "<br />" + evidence);}
function clearForm() {
     document.getElementById('txtarea').innerHTML = "";
}
</script>
```

Here is one of the 7 textfields that I have (I have the `onkeyup` which covers type and paste, but I don't know what to use for drag and drop):

```
<form class="right_aligned" name="form" method="get" action="" id="form"   onkeyup="format()" onmouseup="format()" ondrop="format()">

<div style="float: left;"><input ondblclick="this.value=''" type="text" name="publication" value="Publication..." id="publication" style="border:1px solid;border-color:#B0B0B0;width:225px;padding:4px;margin:10px;color: #000;"  
ondrop="format()" ondragover="{this.value=''; this.style.color='#000';}" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) {this.value=''; this.style.color='#000';}"  onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value=this.defaultValue; this.style.color='#000';}"></div>
```

...and here is the `contenteditable` div that the text is output to:

```
<div CONTENTEDITABLE id="txtarea" ondblclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null);" style="float:left;overflow:auto;padding:5px;background-color:#FFF;border:1px solid;border-color:#B0B0B0;outline:none;width:213px;height:260px;font-size:.75em;margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:5px" type="text"></div>
```

By the way, this is for a Firefox extension, so cross browser is not an issue. It just has to work in Firefox.

Comment: Can you provide an example, for instance on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: How did `ondrop` not work? Because basically, it should.

Comment: @Tomalak - The problem is that the changed text does not happen until AFTER the ondrop fires. http://jsfiddle.net/rREsh/

Comment: @Tomalak - Whoops; I used `innerHTML` instead of `value`. It still doesn't work without some kind of callback, though: http://jsfiddle.net/rREsh/2/

Comment: @Jared Farrish: I took a look at your example. That is as far as I could get as well. It still requires me to click outside of the textbox (onblur) before it fires. For example, Google has somehow figured it out. I checked, and sure enough, you can type, paste AND drop text into the search bar and Google instant searches, but I don't know how they are doing that.

Comment: @Glen - I fixed your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CnAqS/1/ There were some issues, such as you don't need to put `script` blocks in the Javascript box, and when you do a `setTimeout`/`setInterval`, your first argument either has to be an anonymous function or an `eval` string of code (use the anonymous function method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be another way out there, but you can use `setTimeout` with a 1 millisecond time and it seems to work just fine:

```
<p>Duis nunc nisl, luctus nec auctor id, iaculis eu nibh. Nunc odio velit, pretium et scelerisque eget, auctor eget erat. Cras id nulla nec odio vestibulum egestas ac in mi. Vivamus mollis suscipit condimentum. Sed laoreet eros ut lorem tempor porttitor. Etiam eget erat at lacus facilisis aliquam eget id purus.</p>
<br/>
<textarea ondrop="formatOnDrop(this)" onchange="formatOnChange(this)" id="textarea"></textarea>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="inputtext" ondrop="formatOnDrop(this)" onchange="formatOnChange(this)"/>

function formatOnDrop(el){
    formatElement = el;
    //alert('ondrop: ' + el.id + ' was changed to ' + el.value);
    setTimeout(function(){format()},1);
}
function formatOnChange(el){
    formatElement = el;
    //alert('onchange: ' + el.id + ' was changed to ' + el.value);
    setTimeout(function(){format()},1);
}
function format() {
    alert('format: ' + formatElement.id + ' was changed to ' + formatElement.value);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rREsh/3/

Note, the `formatOnChange()` function is never called when selecting and dropping text, but it does fire `onblur` when copying and pasting.

Comment: Jared Farrish: I'm not quite sure what is going on here, but the example still requires that the textbox loses focus. I wasn't thinking of actually using the setTimeout unless the onmouseup event was in fact firing a split second before the new text was entered. Do you think my reasoning is correct that you propose using setTimeout?

Comment: FYI, some browsers (like Chrome) don't fire ondrop without a lot more complicated implementation.  Also, he's now using a contenteditable DIV (which I don't think was disclosed when he first posted) which changes which events one can use.

Comment: @Glen - I've been thinking about it and I think you'll actually need to use `setInterval` and create an observer that watches your element and detects when the value has been changed. The above was when I wasn't really understanding what you were trying to do (posting code and a working demo works really well on this site). I believe that Google Instant Search uses an observer.

Comment: I wanted to let you know that I did finally get it to work by delaying the event after the text was dropped into the field. Thanks for the post.